# Google map pod installation is failed?

Tags: objective-c

I've have one question about pod installation. Error 
"[!] The dependency `GoogleMaps` is not used in any concrete target."

Comment: Make your question clear !

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose proper target in terminal after that you can install the pod refer the site of pod.

Comment: Naive question.. how does one do this?  I've just gotten the same error.

Comment: Go in Terminal write cd and than drag your folder where your project is. press enter and now install pods